# Is there any android API to get the file type using file format

Tags: android

I am working on an android application and need to filter files using their file format. What I exactly want to do is this:

input: "jpg" => output: "image"

input: "mp3" => output: "audio"

input: "mov" => output: "video"

Is there any android API to do this or I have to manually store this information in my app.

Comment: you can get mime type from which you will be fairly able to get your desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MimeTypeMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap.html) class which will return some thing like this 'text/plain'.
You can also read up on mime types [here](http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html)

```
// the File name or Url
public static String getMimeType(String url)
{
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```

Comment: I just saw the link you have given. It gives the detailed name of the format but not the category I want

Comment: [Web Foundations : Mime types Complete List](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/) is more complete

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this manually, if you need particular file types or if you want to find file mime type you can use mime library like this.

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = "image.jpg";
    String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
    String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
    System.out.println(extension);
    if(extension = "jpg"){
        #do something
    }
    }
}
```

Or

```
public static String getMimeType(String url){
    String type = null;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    return type;
}
```